# Макрос в microsoft word

Tags: макрос

Добрый день. поздравляю всех с наступившем. возник вопрос: можно ли написать макрос который будет подцепляться к картам (google, yandex)  и по нажатии кнопки вычислять расстояние от А до Б

Answer (score 1):

Из VBA можно получить данные по URL'у:

```
Dim result As String
Dim objHttp As Object
Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHttp.Open "GET", "http://www.google.com/", False
objHttp.Send ""

result = objHttp.ResponseText
```

У Google Maps есть API, позволяющее вычислять расстояние между точками: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/?hl=ru

Всё что нужно - это сформировать запрос к Google Maps API и распарсить ответ.